# Where can I find the 64bit Minimal CD?

Tags: 64-bit, downloads, lvm, ubuntu-minimal

Where can I find the Minimal install 64bit version? Is it possible to encrypt partition with the Minimal Minimal version (like with the alternative version)?

Answer (score 2):

The link to the minimal for 12.04 64bit is:

[mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

Other versions can be found from here:

[Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Not sure if it is possible to encrypt with the minimal.

Comment: "minimal" is a bit of a misnomer.  It really is the network installer because it downloads the packages from the network instead of having them on the cd already.  In other words, it's just the alternate installer without the base set of packages already on the cd.

Comment: You can also use it, to install just a small system - without gnome/unity. For this, you just have to select the command-line-installation mode.